# How do I Curl command line POST form data returning HTML page with answer

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, curl, post, forms

I am trying to read a single value from a web enabled device. The device has a simple Post form which when will return an HTML page. This works fine from the browser, but not from the command line:

```
# curl -H "Content-Type: text/html"   -X POST -d '{"FGSP":"Read","D900":"100  ","D901":"0    "}' http://192.168.9.187/GSP.htm
```

Returns:

```
<div id="page">
 <form name="param" method="post">
  <table width="750">
   <tr><td class="cntr">Parameter number</td>
       <td class="cntr"><input name="D900" type="text" value="0    "></input></td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="cntr">Parameter value</td>
       <td class="cntr"><input name="D901" type="text" value="0     "></input></td>
       <td class="errr">&nbsp                                     </td></tr>
   <tr class="cntr"><td><input type="submit" name="FGSP" value="Read"></input></td>
       <td><input type="submit" name="FGSP" value="Write"></input></td>           </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</div>
```

This is incorrect as D900 should have a value of 100 and D901 should have a value of 5 on a successful post. So I assume the post parameters did not get passed correctly?

If I do the same from the browser in chrome it works:

[image: Chrome submission of form]

How do I duplicate what the web browser is doing from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This post request was to an embedded system and it seems the order of the parameters matters. Thus:

```
curl -X POST -H "FGSP: Read" -H "D900: 100" -H "D901: 0" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "extra-token: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" -d 'D900=100&D901=0&FGSP=Read' "http://192.168.9.187/GSP.htm"
```

gives the right answer. The curl command also needs the extra token with quite a long length, (I assume to pad the header in some way).